# Python - too many values to unpack

Tags: python, string, tuples, unpack

I have a tuple containing string and a list of string as below:

```
test = ('str1',['1', '2'])
for a,b in test:
    print(a,b)
```

I want to unpack in a way that I can get **[('str1','1'),('str1','2')]**.

However I am getting "**ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**".

If I print length of test, it comes as 2. So not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: The first element of your tuple is `"str1"`, the second is a list `["1", "2"]`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `test` has two elements, you're attempting to iterate over tuples which won't work because `test` has no tuples (it's a tuple itself).

So this works:

```
test = [('str1',['1', '2'])]
for a,b in test:
    print(a,b)
```

Or, to get what you want, as a list:

```
print([(test[0], item) for item in test[1]])
```

You can also iterate in that way:

```
test = ('str1',['1', '2'])
for item in test[1]:
    print(test[0], item)
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the fundamental difference between iterating over tuples vs iterating over list?

Comment: There isn't, you only have to make sure that you're iterating over things that you can unpack in the way you specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` function to implement that:

```
>>> seq = ['1', '2']
>>> print(zip(['str']*len(seq), seq))
[('str', '1'), ('str', '2')]
```

Answer (score 1):

"Too many values to unpack" means exactly that. Let's look at the elements in `test`:

```
test = ('str1',['1', '2'])
for a,b in test:
    print(a,b)
```

Each element in `test` will be unpacked into two variables. The first element is `'str1'`, and the second one is `['1', '2']`. `'str1'` is a string with four characters, so, unpacked, it would need four variables. However, you only provide two, `a` and `b`. That's the error.

To get the output you want, I recommend unpacking as follows:

```
a,b = test
```

Now `a` is `'str1'`, and `b` is `['1', '2']`. You can then loop through the values in `b`:

```
for item in b:
    print(a, item)
```

Result:

```
str1 1
str1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code iterates over each item in `test`; first `'str1'`, then `['1', '2']`. The problem is when you try to do `a, b = 'str1'` (this is what the `for` loop is doing). There are `4` values in `'str1'`, but only two variables to which you're trying to assign them.

Here's one way to do what you actually want:

```
test = ('str1',['1', '2'])

test_str, test_list = test

for b in test_list:
    print(test_str, b)
```

In this code, `test_str` is `'str1'` and `test_list` is `['1', '2']`. Then you iterate over `test_list`, and just reference `test_str` to get `'str1'`.