# Iterate over list to get values in a specified sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, tuples

I had an initial tuple, over which I was trying to iterate to perform further calculations. However, I end up having an error "`too many values to unpack`" which was solved by following suggestions from this question asked previously([Python - too many values to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128095/python-too-many-values-to-unpack)). However, right now after converting it to a list, I have another error `'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'`.

My code looks like this:

```
Z=[([A,3],[A1,6])]  #A and A1 are 2x2 matrices 
y=[]
for data,label in Z:

    x = data.reshape((4,))
    y.append(int(label))
```

I can understand the cause of the error. In this case, I want the loop to run two times (because I have two sets of data [A-3,A1-6]) and `data, label` to be: `A`, `3` and `A1`, `6`. But it is being misread as `data = [A,3]` and `label = [A1,6]`.

What would be the proper way to loop through this list and generate data the way I want?

N.B: The `Z` doesn't need to be a list, I can change it to a tuple if that makes life easier.

Comment: Why do you have the tuple inside a list?

Comment: Are your variables actually named that way in your code?

Comment: Please share the entire error message. _However, right now after converting it to a list, I have another error 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'._ Do you understand the issue?

Comment: The error was solved by using the accepted answer. I could understand the cause of the error but couldn't find an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tuple is inside a list. You're just iterating over the list, but not over the tuple elements. You need nested loops.

```
for t in Z:
    for data, label in t:
        x = data.reshape(4,)
        y.append(int(label))
```

You don't need the nested loops if you get rid of the list.

```
Z=([A,3],[A1,6])  #A and A1 are 2x2 matrices 
y=[]
for data,label in Z:
    x = data.reshape((4,))
    y.append(int(label))
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my issue. But is there any simpler way to group the data other than having the tuple inside the list?

Comment: @Schneider Just choose one, a list or a tuple. No need to nest. `[[A,3],[A1,6]]` or `([A,3],[A1,6])`

Comment: I initially had only a tuple `Z`. That gave me an error as mentioned in the original question. The rest of the code is similar.

Comment: You didn't post the original code, so I don't know what you did wrong. I've posted how to do it correctly.